# Room database error : IllegalStateException on Migration

Tags: android, android-room, database-migration

I use Room persistence library for my database application. I've written a migration strategy to **add a new** table to existing database. I'm facing the following error.

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: table_audio_book(com.ridmik.app.audio_book.model.AudioBookInDb).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='table_audio_book', columns={book_path=Column{name='book_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, stream=Column{name='stream', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, user_id=Column{name='user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_data=Column{name='audio_book_data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_id=Column{name='audio_book_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_name=Column{name='audio_book_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, stream_path=Column{name='stream_path', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, table_audio_book_row_id=Column{name='table_audio_book_row_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, last_closing_time=Column{name='last_closing_time', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}

     Found:
    TableInfo{name='table_audio_book', columns={user_id=Column{name='user_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_chapter_name=Column{name='audio_book_chapter_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_data=Column{name='audio_book_data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_id=Column{name='audio_book_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, audio_book_name=Column{name='audio_book_name', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, row_id=Column{name='row_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, last_closing_time=Column{name='last_closing_time', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

**My Model Class:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "table_audio_book")
data class AudioBookInDb (
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "table_audio_book_row_id")
        val rowId: Long,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_book_id")
        val bookId: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_book_name")
        val bookName: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "stream_path")
        val streamPath: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "book_path")
        val bookPath: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "stream")
        val stream: Boolean,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "audio_book_data")
        val audioBookData: String,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "user_id")
        val userId: Int,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "last_closing_time")
        val lastClosingTime: Long
)
```

**My Migration Snippet:**

```
public static final Migration MIGRATION_6_7 = new Migration(6, 7) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        String createTableAudioBook = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_audio_book` (`table_audio_book_row_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," +
                " `audio_book_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `audio_book_name` TEXT, `book_path` TEXT, `stream_path` TEXT, `stream` INTEGER NOT NULL, `audio_book_data` TEXT," +
                " `user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `last_closing_time` INTEGER NOT NULL)";
        database.execSQL(createTableAudioBook);

        Timber.d("Upgrading Database from version 6 to 7");
    }
};
```

***Can anyone put me in right direction on how to solve this?***

Comment: The "found table info" in the error message includes columns that do no exist in your migration statement to create the table, for example: `audio_book_chapter_name`.  This suggests that `table_audio_book` already exists, so `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` does nothing. Try adding `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_audio_book` to your migration.

Comment: @BobSnyder Thanks man. Worked like a charm! The problem was I when I created the table I used `fallbackDestructiveMigration()`. So it worked okay. And later when I tried to add the migration on it since table was already created this problem arose. Your answer did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BobSnyder said I've solved it by dropping the table first and the recreating the table. And it worked like a charm. So I'm putting his comment as answer in case anyone needs it in the future.